# Update ArrayList of Specific Instance

Tags: java

This has been confusing me for a while, picture this

```
public class someObject {

private ArrayList<Player> listOfPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
private String name;

public void addPlayer(Player player){
    listOfPlayers.add(player);
}
}
```

Multiple instances of this object can be created during the game, what i don't understand is how do you update the ArrayList of a specific instance, for example

There are 10 instances currently of the someObject class Player 1, 2 and so on. Player 5 wants to add a player to his listOfPlayers, how would i handle getting the arraylist of his specific instance where he is currently in the listOfPlayers.

What i have been doing is

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i ++){ //ArrayList<someObject>
        someObject temp = someObject.get(i);
        if (temp.listOfPlayers.contains(player)){
            return true;
        }
}
```

Which works but it seems so wrong using for loops in every getter and setter of the someObjects class, is there a better way than this ?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution/alternative would be using a Map.

```
Map<someObject, List<Players>> objPlayersMap=  new HashMap.....
```

Later, you can check your condition just like

```
objPlaersMap.get(someObject).contains(...
```

Comment: The list is just 1 example, the class has many lists for different things

Comment: So in my main class where the onject is created

someObject o = new someObject();

I can use the objPlaersMap.get(someObject).contains(player);

And that will search the specific player across all active instances?

Comment: How would i add/remove from the list within the map without creating a new list everytime?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, u can modify your "Player" class and add an id. With setter and getter u can handle these with this id. Its an idea, if u wanna prefer it more.

Comment: They do have an ID, how would i get the instance where the players ID is in the list without looping over all the instances?

Comment: U have 2 ways: use a map to get the specific instance (like @baki answer) or u remanage ur ArrayList<someObject> insert action. U can  add @ example player 5 at ArrayList<someObject>[4]. So u can get everytime the right instance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a map with the name of the player as a key. In that way you can get the list easily without a loop

```
Map<String, List<Players>> players =  new HashMap<String,List<Players>>();
players.put("player1", new SomeObject());
players.put("player2", new SomeObject());
....
```

after that you do that:

```
List<Players> player1 = players.get("player1");
```

Comment: How? There will be multiple lists, listOfPlayers, listOfSpawns for example, how would i get the instance by the ID (name) if possible?

Comment: You can use the key to make the difference or if you want you can create a map for each type of list